# jq select using a boolean attribute in deep nested array

Tags: json, select, jq

How can i select / filter all connection with field.usesEncryption is true using jq from JSON data below

```
{
  "connections": {
    "connection": [
      {
        "field": [
          {
            "id": "url",
            "encryptedValueSet": false,
            "usesEncryption": false,
            "componentOverride": false,
            "useDefault": false
          },
          {
            "id": "user",
            "encryptedValueSet": false,
            "usesEncryption": false,
            "componentOverride": false,
            "useDefault": false
          },
          {
            "id": "password",
            "encryptedValueSet": true,
            "usesEncryption": true,
            "componentOverride": false,
            "useDefault": false
          }
        ],
        "id": "3ea89002-51f5-4369-9539-63c3bd406a64"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried following but not working as desired

```
jq '. | select(.connections.connection[].field[] | .usesEncryption==true)' EnvironmentExtensions.json
jq '. | .connections.connection[].field[] | select(.usesEncryption==true)' EnvironmentExtensions.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the inner array, either use (requires jq 1.7):

```
.connections.connection[].field[] |= select(.usesEncryption)
```

or (works with jq 1.6)

```
.connections.connection[].field |= map(select(.usesEncryption))
```

Alternatively, rebuild both arrays (jq 1.6):

```
.connections.connection |= map(.field |= map(select(.usesEncryption)))
```

Comment: - Not working with jq 1.6 but does work with jq 1.7
- Error below with both jq 1.6 and jq 1.7
jq: error (at C:/Users/asamuel/AppData/Local/Temp/EnvironmentExtensions.json:32): Cannot index string with string "usesEncryption"

Comment: @AnilSamuel I verified locally now with 1.6 and 1.7: the first program requires 1.7, but the second program works with 1.6 too. None of the programs generate an error, but the first program generates incorrect output under 1.6. I previously only had jqplay.org available, which apparently already uses 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Filter below works but the top level structure is lost from output

```
jq '.connections.connection[].field[] | select(.usesEncryption)' EnvironmentExtensions.json
```